# Is it possible to have a power series $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=\left \lceil{x-\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor}\right \rceil$?

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is it possible to have a **power series** $f(x)$ like that: $f(x)=\left \lceil{x-\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor}\right \rceil$?

Comment: But $f(x)$ is discontinuous whereas any finite polynomial is continuous.

Comment: But there are discontinuous **infinite** polynomials

Comment: There's no such thing as an infinite polynomial, all polynomials have finite degree.

Comment: What about the Taylor expension of $\sin x$?

Comment: The Taylor series expansion for $\sin{(x)}$ is a representation for the function which uses a convergent power series. A power series is not the same as a polynomial.

Comment: If your power series converges at some non-zero $x_0$ then it is **analytic** for $|x|< x_0$ and the only analytic function which is constant $=1$ on $(0,|x_0|)$ is the trivial power series $1$. The first theorem to know is that a non-constant analytic function has isolated zeros (here you'll substract $1$ to find it has non-isolated zeros thus it is constant)

Answer (score 0):

Your $f(x)$ is $=0$ for all $x\in{\mathbb Z}$ and $=1$ for all $x\notin{\mathbb Z}$. It is sufficient to check the $x\in [0,1[\>$ to check this. There is no polynomial $f$ that can deliver such values, e.g., because polynomials are continuous. By the way, there are no "infinite polynomials".

Comment: Infinite polynomial is a polynom that 
there is no degree you can say it's the "highest" degree